# You have 28 cards and 6 envelopes (labeled 1,2, ..,6). In how many ways can you put the 28 cards into the envelopes if...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

a) The cards are distinct?

b) The cards are identical?

c) The cards are identical, and no envelope can remain empty?

I am very stuck on this problem. The closest I have gotten is solving for part B, which I believe is a stars and bars problem, but the answer I submitted (6,724,520) is incorrect, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What exact calculation did you do to arrive at 6724520?

Comment: Since I believe it is a stars and bars, I used the formula (n + r + 1)C(r + 1), with N being the number of cards and R being the number of envelopes, leading to 35C7.

Comment: Plus one?  Check again the sign.

Comment: This got me the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)  Choose which envelope the first letter goes into.  Then choose which envelope the second letter goes into.  Then choose which envelope the third letter goes into... repeat the process until completed

(b)  Yes, this is a stars and bars problem.  How many bars are necessary however?  It should require *one less bar* than the number of categories you are grouping them into.

(c)  This is also a stars and bars problem, except this time rather than looking for non-negative solutions we are looking for strictly positive solutions.

Depending on how you were taught, you may have been taught the solution to the stars-and-bars problem described by part (b) first and learned to modify that approach to fit part (c) instead., or you might have learned it in reverse having learned part (c) first and used that approach and modified it to fit part (b).

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped.